# New mail notifications (by Evolution) suddenly stopped working

Tags: 12.04, notification, evolution

Immediately following one of the latest Ubuntu system updates<sup>1</sup>, notifications about newly arrived mails stopped working. The corresponding plugin<sup>2</sup> is still enabled, and I'm not aware of having changed any related configuration. Just to make sure, I've also checked the accounts' settings<sup>3</sup> – but couldn't find anything related here. Neither can it be the "global notification daemon", as `notify-send "Test" "Dummy notification"` brings up the notification as expected.

I'm out of ideas where else I could check (some notification service that needs to be started explicitly but somehow failed? Notifications for other apps like Skype still pop up, and `notify-send` works as expected). I've already checked syslog for errors, but none are shown.

I'm running Evolution `3.4.2-1ubuntu3.1~stracciatellappa+precise1` on 12.04 here. I've checked for the `mail-notification-evolution` package, it's not installed<sup>4</sup> – but as notifications worked before the last reboot, this cannot be the reason.

In case it matters: I'm using LXDE as desktop environment, but Gnome desktop is *installed* as well (though not selected as default). Again, as it worked in the past (before that last update/reboot), all required components should be available.

**Update:** I've just figured `evolution-indicator` should be responsible for notifications here. But there were no changes to that package either within the last year.

Any ideas what I could check/adjust to make notifications from Evolution work again?

---

<sup>**1:** I'm not sure which update exactly it was (there were no updates for Evolution itself); the issue started after the latest reboot. I assume it were the last kernel updates (3.2.0-94), but cannot tell for sure. Walking through the list of latest updates/installs in `/var/log/apt/history.log` doesn't reveal anything I'd recognize as related.</sup>

<sup>**2:** *Edit › Plugins › Notifications for new mails*</sup>

<sup>**3:** *Edit › Settings › (Account_Name)*</sup>

<sup>**4:** according to `dpkg -l mail-notification-evolution` it never has been installed – it doesn't even have an install candidate in the [stracciatella PPA](https://launchpad.net/~janvitus/+archive/ubuntu/gnomestracciatella?field.series_filter=precise) I've used to install Evolution 3.4.2 from quite some time ago; the package in the "standard repo" depends on Evolution < 3.3 and thus cannot be(en) used anyway</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what finally did it – but currently, notifications are working again (and I hope they keep working):

- as root, I've executed `ln -s /usr/lib/evolution/3.2/plugins/* /usr/lib/evolution/3.4/plugins/`<sup>1</sup>: If that has been the culprit, how did it work before? Neither Evolution nor the Evolution-Indicator have been updated in the past 12 months.
- checked and "toggled" notification settings (each one twice, so I've ended up not changing them but triggering Evo to write them again), see note 1 in the question. Did that before, and it didn't help.
- after the above, restarted Evolution. I did that before more than once without any effect on the issue.

Maybe it was the combination of tasks performed – or the two symlinked files in the `plugin` directory triggered some "re-configuration of plugins" in Evolution, solving the issue as a side-effect (which is what I assume).

---

<sup>**1:** `evolution-indicator` plugins were located in the `3.2` directory only – and were the only (two) files residing there</sup>